# Output Buffer Requirements for MKL FFT

Tags: c++, intel-mkl

I am writing a program in C++ using MKL 2018.1 FFT functionality for 2-D FFT (rank=2). The MKL reference does not appear to explicitly state what the output size is for `DftiComputeForward` and `DftiComputeBackward` (true?).

What are the required output buffers sizes for a Real-to-complex forward and Complex-to-Real computations using the following type of descriptor?

```
MKL_LONG status, l[2];
l[0] = 32; l[1] = 100;
status = DftiCreateDescriptor(&my_desc1_handle, DFTI_SINGLE,
    DFTI_REAL, 2, l);
status = DftiCommitDescriptor(my_desc1_handle);
status = DftiSetValue(my_desc1_handle, DFTI_PLACEMENT, DFTI_NOT_INPLACE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Intel Math Kernel (MKL)  Library Reference Manual specified the sizes in the section "DFTI_CCS_FORMAT for One-dimensional Transforms" for Real to Complex transformations.

For 1-D Transforms:

[image: MKL 1D Sizes]

And for 2-D Transforms is says:

> DFTI_CCS_FORMAT for Two-dimensional Transforms The following figure
>   illustrates the storage of a two-dimensional (2D) M-by-N
>   conjugate-even sequence in a real array for the CCS packed format.
>   This format requires an array of size (M+2)-by-(N+2). Row-major layout
>   and zero-based indexing are used. Different colors mark logically
>   separate parts of the result. "n/u" means "not used".

[image: MKL 2D Sizes]